# Qualtrics trigger message - custom formatting

Tags: conditional-formatting, qualtrics

Good morning everyone,
I have been creating a survey in Qualtrics and configured the mail message going out after each submission. I have the following code inside the body of the text. The last field (CODE) retrieves from the variables a numeric value = 0 or 1. I would need to format one of the lines in the message (for example SELECTED) with a green text colour if CODE=1 and red text color if CODE=0.

```
SCORE: ${gr://SC_8wExY0SJDXfJ2UC/Score}<br />
DOMANDA: ${q://QID8/QuestionText}<br />
TUTTE RISPOSTE :&nbsp;${q://QID8/ChoiceGroup/DisplayedChoices}<br />
SELECTED: ${q://QID8/ChoiceGroup/SelectedChoices}<br />
UNSELECTED:&nbsp;${q://QID8/ChoiceGroup/UnselectedChoices}<br />
RECODE: ${q://QID8/SelectedChoicesRecode}<br />
CODE:&nbsp;${gr://SC_cIIBMpIqBI6Jlpc/Score}<br />
```

Can you help me?
Thank you very much.
Kind regards, Stefano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign an embedded data field equal to score in the survey flow, then set a color based on that field:

```
code = ${gr://SC_cIIBMpIqBI6Jlpc/Score}
color = red
If code Greater than 0
   color = green
```

Then add html to your email text:

```
<span style='color:${e://Field/color}'>
SELECTED: ${q://QID8/ChoiceGroup/SelectedChoices}<br />
</span>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I had to figure out how to enter the logic in the workflow but in the end it worked beautifully!!